# Convert string stored in string to a function (Python)

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, function

If I have the name of a function stored in a string like so:

*foo = 'some_function'*

Assuming that I could call *bar.some_function.baz()*, how can I do that using foo? Obviously this example doesnt explain why I couldnt just use *some_function* but in the actual code I iterate over a list of names of functions that I want to call.

To make it even clearer, if *bar.some_function.baz()* prints *'Hello world!'* then some code, using *foo* but not *some_function* should do the same. Is it perhaps possible to use the value of the string and *exec()*?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean you want to *dynamically look up an attribute*? Use `getattr()` for that.

Comment: In your case: `getattr(bar, foo).baz()`.

Comment: Oh.. makes sense, thank you. I wasnt sure getattr() worked like that. Thanks. (Sorry for the duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

If it's in a class, you can use getattr:

```
class MyClass(object):
def install(self):
      print "In install"

method_name = 'install' # set by the command line options
my_cls = MyClass()

method = None
try:
method = getattr(my_cls, method_name)
except AttributeError:
raise NotImplementedError("Class `{}` does not implement `{}`".format(my_cls.__class__.__name__, method_name))
```

method()
or if it's a function:

```
def install():
   print "In install"

method_name = 'install' # set by the command line options
possibles = globals().copy()
possibles.update(locals())
method = possibles.get(method_name)
if not method:
 raise NotImplementedError("Method %s not implemented" %    method_name)
method()
```